# How do you get the raw data of an Excel file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

The European Union (EU) provides an Excel file that has data on trade between various countries. Their Excel file, however, only shows data between countries based on a filter function. It seems they have done this through some Excel transformation.

I would like to see all the possible filter options. Or, in other words, all the raw data that is "behind" the filter options of the Excel file.

Example attached as two screenshots below. Link to the data also below. As the screenshot shows, you need to filter in the top-left corner to view the subsets of data. I would like see the entire dataset in one worksheet, at once.

Anyone know how to do this?

Here is a link to download the file: https://circabc.europa.eu/ui/group/7fc51410-46a1-4871-8979-20cce8df0896/library/97a8fd73-3a4c-49d7-974e-f52f1f2cf170/details?download=true

Thanks! I'm on a Macbook if that's relevant.

Screenshot 1:
[image: Excel worksheet (filter in top-left corner)]

Screenshot 2:
[image: Filter dropdown menu]

Comment: Try to right-click on sheet tab and choose Unhide (or Show) sheet - there are two hidden sheets, **data** (55218 rows) and **lists**

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a ton.